# C++, RVO, NRVO и локальные статические объекты

Tags: c++, static, rvo

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
struct Object
{
  // ...
};

struct CompoundObject
{
  // ...
  Object object;
};

CompoundObject get()
{
  static Object object;

  CompoundObject compoundObject = {object};

  return compoundObject;
}

int main()
{
  CompoundObject compoundObject = get();
}
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: учитывая возможные `RVO` и `NRVO` оптимизации, есть ли гарантия того, что `object` НЕ БУДЕТ перемещен?

Если такие гарантии есть, я бы хотел знать, на чем они основываются.

Comment: В этом примере `object` нигде не перемещается, а RVO / NRVO к нему вообще не применимы

Comment: @VTT, почему не применимы?

Comment: `object` один раз точно копируется (`= {object};`), а потом при возврате из функции либо перемещается, либо нет (нет - если срабатывает NRVO для `compoundObject`). NRVO - на усмотрение компилятора.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, почему один раз - точно?

Comment: Потому что RVO применяются к объектам непосредственно создаваемым в `return`, а NRVO  к локальным переменным с автоматическим хранением. `object` - это ни то, ни другое, а вот `compoundObject` как раз подпадает под NRVO

Comment: *"почему один раз - точно?"* А что вы рассчитывали получить на этой строчке? [N]RVO - не подходит, там ведь нет `return`. Перемещение тоже не подходит, `object` ведь lvalue.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, даже если функция возвращает копию, компилятор все равно может сделать перемещение. Меня беспокоит теоретическая ситуация, когда компилятор выполнит перемещение (неожиданное) статичного объекта. Я никак не могу найти в `Стандарте` объяснение, когда компилятор может применить перемещение вместо копирования, а когда нет. И как эта оптимизация относится к статичному объекту.

Comment: [N]RVO влияет на то, будет ли перемещаться весь `compoundObject`, или нет. Он никак не связан с копированием `object` в строчке `CompoundObject compoundObject = {object};`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, что мешает вызвать для `object` конструктор перемещения?

Comment: То, что он lvalue?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я не совсем понимаю, почему локальные объекты в одном случае подлежат перемещению при оптимизации, а в другом - не подлежат.